# Plotting the real positive solution to a parametric equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have the following parametric equation
$$
x^2-a=0
$$
where $a$ is a given parameter. I would like to plot the nonnegative real root ($\sqrt{a}$) using NSolve as $a$ varies from $0$ to $1$. Can someone please teach me how to do this in Mathematica 10 Student Edition? Thank you very much!

I tried

```
Plot[NSolve[
  x^2 - a == 0 && Element[x, Reals] == True && x >= 0, {x}], {a, 0, 1}]
```

but the output was empty.

p.s. My actual equation is much more complicated and I don't have an analytical solution, hence NSolve.

Comment: `Plot[x /. Solve[x^2 - a == 0, {x}], {a, 0, 1}]`

Comment: A useful method to understand why a plot is empty, replace Plot with Table and adjust the plot range to give enough values.  Changing your code to Table[NSolve[x^2 - a == 0 && Element[x, Reals] == True && x >= 0, {x}], {a, 0, 1, 1/4}] will perhaps show you WHY it isn't working.

Comment: The Bill's answer is pedagogic, but I would prefer to give you a direct answer. If you try your code for `NSolve `with some numeric  `a` value, say, `a=1`you will see the following: `a = 1; NSolve[x^2 - a == 0 && Element[x, Reals] == True && x >= 0, x] `yields the following: `{{x -> 1.}}`. This is what you get under the operator `Plot `. For this reason `Plot`returns and empty thing. One workaround is to use the belisarius construct given above.

Comment: @Community I think, this question is off-topic, since it is based on a simple syntax error.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I would rather say it's a duplicate of this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/193